# What is the use of const in the given function when the member variables are changed by the function?

Tags: c++, constants

```
class StatDemo
{
   private: static int x;
   int y;
   public: void setx(int a) const { x = a; }
   void sety(int b) const { y = b; }
   int getx() {return x; }
   int gety() {return y; }
} ;
```

What is the use of const when the member variables are changed by the function??

Comment: "What is the use of const..." To cause compiler error?

Comment: It looks like you've mistakenly made the setters const, and the getters non-const.  It should be the other way around.  And this stuff should all be _inside_ the class definition, not after it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

methods not marked `const` cannot be called on a `const` object (or ref or pointer to a `const` object).

```
StatDemo sd;
StatDemo const & sdr = sd;
sdr.get(x); // error because getx isn't marked const
```

However, that means that all the data members accessed from within a method marked `const` are also `const`, so you cannot change them (without playing tricks).

That's why your `setx` won't compile -- `x` is const within those methods.

Comment: `x` is static, so it isn't affected by `const` qualification on `setx`

Comment: @Caleth fixed, thank you :) I didn't catch that it was static.

Answer (score 0):

> What is the use of const when the member variables are changed by the
>   function?

As @songyuanyao correctly mentioned, to cause compile errors.

Yet, it is rather a convention. You may still modify members via `const_cast` on `this`, or via marking members `mutable`.

There's a difference between logical and physical constness, as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3830367/difference-between-logical-and-physical-const-ness).

> Why may we still modify `non-const` `static` members in `const` methods?

A `non-static` method of a class has `this` as a parameter. `const` qualifier on a method makes `this` constant (and triggers a compile error when the convention's violated).

A `static` member isn't related to `this` in any way: it is the only one for every object of a class. That's why the constness of a method (i.e. the constness of `this`) has no impact on `static` members of a class.