# Best practice when accessing a non-const method of a member pointer from a const-method

Tags: c++, oop, constants

Consider the following situation

```
class A
{
public:
    void someFunc() const
    {
         b->nonConstFunction(); //this is a non const function in the class B
    }

private:
    B* b;
};
```

In the constant function `someFunc()` I can call any nonconstant method of `b` and it will compile. So the function `someFunc()` is somehow not a true const function. But all best practices says that one should put `const` anywhere you can. Should this advice be applied also here?
May be declaring the function `void someFunc()` nonconstant is more honest then `void someFunc() const`. Or may be there is a more general advice to handle this kind of things?

Comment: It really depends on what `class A` represents. There's no one size fits all here.

Comment: take a look at [`mutable`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cv) => it's perfectly for some case like that: define a variable which can be modified in a const environment because it's doesn't care regardless of class instance (IMHO, a good example is mutex => mutex has to be modified in a const env)

Comment: If you have access to a copy, you might want to read the item in Effective C++ about logical vs. bitwise constness; that's exactly the confusion you have at the moment. [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3830367/difference-between-logical-and-physical-const-ness#3830484) has some discussion on it.

Comment: "not a true `const` function" and yet `b` isn't modified right? So it depends. Also relevant might be the proposed [`propagate_const`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/propagate_const)

Comment: Generally use const to mark methods that don't alter the object. Unfortunately some objects cache requests for data, so a method is logically const in terms of external behaviour but internally alters the object. Reserve mutable for that relatively rare situation.

Comment: Avoiding the definitions of const which are a little out of scope.  If this is something that concerns you, then use references.

Comment: Please fix the title of your question so that it is useful and describes the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> is somehow not a true const function

well, it depends what you want to express.

1. if `A`'s state logically depends on `b`'s state (this is the implication I get from your question)

   - simplest solution is to give `A` a member of type `B`, instead of using either a pointer or a reference. Then you have a `const B` in your const method, and this expresses your requirement directly
   - next simplest is to just declare the member as `const B *b;` in the first place - obviously this doesn't work if you also need non-const methods of `A` to call non-const methods on `b`.
   - if you need the indirection, another possibility is to use a smart pointer class (I'm not sure if a suitable one already exists) with operator overloads like

     ```
      B* operator->();
      const B* operator->() const;
     ```

     which would give the guarantee you want
2. if `A`'s state does *not* logically depend on `b`'s.

   In this case you don't have a problem: mutating `b` in a `const` method is fine, since `A`'s logical state doesn't change. This might often be the case where you have a pointer to eg. a logger, which would otherwise need lots of mutable members.

Answer (score 2):

It's const if A does not "own" B. Modern C++ expresses that by making b a unique_ptr is A is the owner and a plain pointer if just a link.

Answer (score 1):

It would seem that `C++` views `B` as not being part of `A` but that `A` is *connected* to `B`. As `B` is not *const* then `A` can call its *non-const* methods. But because `A` is *const* you can't make `A` point to a different `B`. If you make `B` a member then you can no longer call its *non-const* methods because its now part of `A`.

I thought using a `std::unique_ptr` would fix this but apparently `std::unique_ptr` returns a *non-const* pointer from its *const* arrow operator `->`.

You could fix this by creating a pointer wrapper that passes the constness on to the contained pointer, something like this:

```
template<typename T>
class const_correct_ptr
{
public:
    const_correct_ptr(std::unique_ptr<T>): p(std::move(p)) {}

    // pass constness onto target
    T* operator->() { return p.get(); }
    T const* operator->() const { return p.get(); }

private:
    std::unique_ptr<T> p;
};

class B
{
public:
    void nonConstFunction() {}
};

class A
{
public:
    A(): b(std::make_unique<B>()) {}

    void someFunc() const
    {
         b->nonConstFunction(); // compile time error!
    }

private:
    const_correct_ptr<B> b;
};
```